# What is the solution to this room maze? I still don't know!

Tags: graph-theory

There are 3 rooms (two on top, one on bottow- like an upside down pyramid) with 12 doors, each room with 5 doors (three doors are shared between multiple rooms). You have to make one solid line (starting anywhere you wish) to go through each of the 12 doors. You cannot go through any room twice. The only "hint" to the only known solution is that it looks like a "fetus" (weird hint, I know). I do not know if the hint is real or not (since I don't have the solution myself). Good luck?[image: (picture of what the rooms look like, doors are represented with 2 lines right next to each other)]

Comment: The traversal is flat-out impossible because there are 4 rooms (plus the outside) with an odd number of doors. Also how do you define "passing through" – is it entering through one door and going out of another?

Comment: Indeed the "cannot go through any room twice" requirement makes this doubly impossible: since all doors must be used there is at least one room that isn't home to an endpoint of the path, and hence will be passed through twice.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel they don't say you can't go through the same door twice. Perhaps just slipping in and out through the same door doesn't count as going through the room. (I'm not saying that wouldn't be silly...)

Comment: It is called the Kônigsberg problem.  The original problem was about land masses connected by bridges.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven_Bridges_of_K%C3%B6nigsberg .  It was generalized to an arbitrary number of places with single or multiple connections.  Applied to your problem it says there is no path that crosses all the doors once.

Comment: Umm.. The "**fetus**" hint, is it about something like *FOLDING* the paper?

Answer (score 1):

All three rooms are equivalent to each other topologically. There is also no requirement that doors be used once; if "going through a room" means entering by one door and exiting by another, there are quite a few solutions:

> One route starts in room A, then goes to B, C and A again, then outside. This handles the internal doors and leaves 8 external ones, each of which is handled by entering and immediately exiting.